# Fabric sudo silently failing

Tags: celery, sudo, fabric

I'm using Fabric 1.6.0 on OS X 10.8.2, running commands on a remote host on Ubuntu Lucid 10.04.

On the server, I can run `sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd restart` to restart the Celery service.

I pass the same command through fabric using:

```
@task
def restart():
    run('sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd restart')
```

Or

```
@task
def restart2():
    sudo('/etc/init.d/celeryd restart')
```

Or use the command line form `fab <task_that_sets_env.host> -- sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd restart`

The command always fails silently - meaning that fabric returns no errors, but celeryd reports that it's not running.

I'm tearing my hair out here! There's nothing relevant in the Celery log file, and AFAIK Fabric should just pass the commands straight through.

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://github.com/mher/celery-deploy. It uses fabric to restart celery nodes on remote hosts

Comment: If you run the same command after SSH-ing into the server, what is the output?

Comment: @Bibhas The command always succeeds when run on the server, and always fails when run via fabric.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm pretty late to the party, and you can downvote me if this doesnt work, but I've had similar problems running other programs in /etc/init.d with fabric. My solution (works with tomcat and mysql) is to add `pty=False`

```
@task
def restart():
    sudo('/etc/init.d/celeryd restart', pty=False)
```

Theres documentation on the option here:

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run